# CancelOperation throws exception from Custom event handler in Umbraco

Tags: c#, event-handling, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.8.1

I have added custom event handler to prevent saving data to validate future dates in date picker

```
ContentService.Saving += delegate (IContentService sender, SaveEventArgs<IContent> args)
{
    foreach (var content in args.SavedEntities.Where(c => c.ContentType.Alias.Equals("profile")))
    {
        var birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(content.Properties["birthDate"].Value);

        if (DateTime.Compare(birthDate ,DateTime.Now) > 0)
        {
            args.CancelOperation(new EventMessage("Invalid Date of Birth", "You can not add futuer date...", EventMessageType.Error));
        }
    }
}
```

It shows error message but it also throws an exception

**Umbraco.Web.Editors.ContentController - Unhandled controller exception occurred
System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.**

and then page redirect to url : 
http://domain.in/umbraco/#/content/content/edit/0

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use args.Cancel = true; instead?

And then add your custom message through args.Messages.Add(...);

Should work, I think, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: It showing error message. but then browser not responding further. and also throws same exception.